# d3js ordinal scale not able to limit pan

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to limit pan. Not sure how to limit when axis is ordinal scale. For linear scale its fine. The problem is even not zoomed, I am able to pan which leaves empty space as everything moves including axis and if zoomed, I want to limit so that we cannot pan beyond limit.

```
var translate = zoom.translate(),
    scale = zoom.scale();

var tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(translate[0], width - width * scale));
var ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(translate[1], height - height * scale));
```

[Here is jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/9rypxf10/)

Comment: If you use d3 v5 (the current version), you can limit panning using `zoom.translateExtent`. d3 v3 does not have this option.

Comment: So is it impossible to limit panning with d3v3?

Comment: @reactdev It is not impossible, but it is a little bit involved. Here is an example of doing it for another type of chart: http://bl.ocks.org/shawnbot/6518285

Comment: It's much easier to set in d3 v5, and d3 v3 is deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: basically I am trying to implement zoom/pan on heatmap chart something like http://bl.ocks.org/aditeyapandey/f10befa4d9e756460cd3

Comment: upgrading to d3 v5 is not an option for me because there are many charts in the project that will require upgrade to v5.

Comment: so you have time to make new charts and try and gets things done in v3 but you don't have time to convert a v3 chart to v5, very unlikely you have hundreds of different types of charts, maybe make a few generic chart types that accept a config and data arguments